# Using Java Selenium, how can I select this element using a unicode value?

Tags: java, selenium, unicode

I am testing using Java & Selenium.

I am trying to execute a click on a close button, which has the following unicode character: `\ue01d`.

OuterHTML on that element looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control btn btn-clear" style="font-family: MapIcons; 
padding: 0px;" value="" type="button">
```

I want to try & select it using the following:

```
String className = "form-control btn btn-clear";
    String htmlElement = "input";
    String textToFind=""; // this should be unicode: \ue01d

    List<WebElement> elements = Common.findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(driver, htmlElement, className);

    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " elements count: " + elements.size());
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        String text = element.getAttribute("value");
        if (text != null) {
            if (text != "") {
                text = text.trim();
                if(text.contains(textToFind)) {
                    return Common.scrollIntoView(element, driver);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```

I want to know what I should put in textToFind. The system does not recognise that square character it has invented. It does not copy & paste this element accurately.

Please note: this value `\ue01d` is NOT a String, it is a Unicode value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the unicode value of your character, you can check, if this value is in the string like this:

```
String s = "some string";
if (s.contains("unicode value")) { // for example '\ue01d'
  System.out.println("Contains!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Not contains");
}
```

in your case it would be like this:

```
String className = "form-control btn btn-clear";
    String htmlElement = "input";
    String textToFind="\\ue01d"; // unicode value

    List<WebElement> elements = Common.findElementsUsingHtmlXpathClass(driver, htmlElement, className);

    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " elements count: " + elements.size());
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        String text = element.getAttribute("value");
        if (text != null) {
            if (text != "") {
                text = text.trim();
                if(text.contains(textToFind)) {
                    return Common.scrollIntoView(element, driver);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
```